# A sound argument for existence of Americas, along al-Biruni's lines?

Tags: history, geophysics

In 11-th century, Al-Biruni computed circumference of Earth with high accuracy, and mapped all then-known terrain. He then argued that the unknown part of the globe cannot be all ocean, predicting existence of large unknown land masses west of Europe (respectively, east of Asia). His argument was that land is denser than water,  and thus land masses must be somehow counterbalanced, and also that the forces that produced masses of land along equator in the known part of the Earth should also act in the unknown one.

Does it make any sense from today's point of view? Suppose that someone possesses the modern level of theoretical knowledge in (geo)-physics, astronomy, etc., but only al-Biruni's knowledge of geography. Could they lay down a sound and plausible argument for the existence of Americas?

**Edit:** the existence of supercontinents in Earth's history is an excellent point, but it doesn't quite invalidate all arguments one can imagine. E. g. if the ratio of the area of land to that of water was roughly constant in time (was it? I couldn't find the answer by a quick search) *and* that constant could be somehow estimated without directly observing, this would indeed show that there ought to be unknown land masses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern geoscience is perfectly OK with the concept of a [supercontinent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinent) (i.e. a single huge continent that takes up an overwhelming fraction of the continental crust present), and there is ample evidence for the formation, breakup and then re-formation of supercontinents multiple times over the Earth's geologic history (with the precise numbers depending on quite how picky you are regarding what does and does not count as a supercontinent, and with evidence becoming weaker the further back in time you look, obviously). [Pangea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea) and [Gondwana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gondwana) are well-known examples.

For an accessible introduction to the supercontinent cycle, try e.g. PBS Eons' video [The Whole Saga of the Supercontinents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfYn9KVya-Q).